# When running a migration unnecessary changes appear in structure.sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After Changing the Schema Format to `sql`

`config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`

Any time a migration is run some unaffected fields get moved around. Is there any way to preserve the order to prevent unnessesary changes from being commited.

[image]

Comment: While migrating changes from your schema file to your database, Rails loves to "migrate" changes the other way as well. Assuming you are having this problem in your development environment, you might be able to resolve the problem by dropping your development database and recreating it from the schema file.